# ElasticSearch Regexp in array

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch stored documents, where in field "kitten" stored values of 2 types: words with numbers and only numbers.
Example:

```
cat8389
fox973
947384
```

I want to get all documents, where in this array stored minimum one only numbers value, and can't write a correct query for it :(

I try this, but it's incorrect:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "kitten": "[0-9 ]+$"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Help me, please...

Comment: FYI: ES patterns are anchored by default, you do not have to/can't use `$`. The pattern must match the whole input. What do you mean by "minimum one only numbers value"? If you want to match digit-only fields,use `"[0-9]+"`

Comment: Thank you. This is correct query: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "kitten": "[0-9]+"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}

Comment: Posted, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ElasticSearch patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators) are anchored by default, and you can't use the end of string `$` anchor (same as start of string `^`). That also means the pattern must match the whole input.

> Most regular expression engines allow you to match any part of a string. If you want the regexp pattern to start at the beginning of the string or finish at the end of the string, then you have to anchor it specifically, using `^` to indicate the beginning or `$` to indicate the end.
>
> **Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.**

So, to match digit-only inputs, use a mere `"[0-9]+"` pattern.